# in diffutils: is there a way in diff output to let diff mark the name if it is a file name or a subdir name?

Tags: diff

in diffutils: is there a way in diff output to let diff mark the name if it is a file name or a subdir name?

when diff shows

only in A: fileORdirname

it is often important to know if the name is a file name or a name of a subdorectory.

Is there a way to let diff mark the name if it is a file name or a subdir name?

Regards